# Align marginnote with text

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginnote

For marginnotes sized the same as the text, the first line of the marginnote is aligned on exactly the same height as the text line.

[image]

---

I however want the marginnotes to be `\footnotesize` and be sans-serif. Setting those specifications using

```tex
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize\sffamily}
```

however leads to the first line of the marginnote not being at the same height as the text.

[image]

---

**How can I align the first line of the marginnote with the line of text, i.e. have the `Ut purus elit` in the marginnote be exactly on the same line as the text on the left?**

---

#### Complete MWE:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\footnotesize\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\\\marginnote{\lipsum[1][2]}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `\strut` before going into `\footnotesize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[fulladjust]{marginnote}
\renewcommand*{\marginfont}{\strut\footnotesize\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]\\\marginnote{\lipsum[1][2]}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 30 seconds faster and same answer +1 :-)

Comment: I was thinking about that too but I noted it messes the horizontal placement of the marginnote, or at least it does on my system, because your snapshot looks fine. Something's weird...

Comment: @campa It is strange to contemplate how a vertical strut can mess with horizontal placement.  In your case, does it do so even on this simple MWE?

Comment: Yes it does, but I also get a no-line-to-end-here error from ``\\`` after `\lipsum`. However I'm working with TL2017, so who knows what else is happening...